# How to make resizable, scrollable sidebar like Facebook's "Chat/Event Ticker"?

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

I am trying to design a collapsible/hide-able sidebar for my web application, in the vain of Facebook's Chat/Event Ticker.  It needs to have two separate sections, separated vertically, and both independently scrollable.

I have tried to implement this using jakiestfu's Snap.js plugin. 
https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/

While this works great, it moves the content on my page out of view, and breaks my `position: fixed` header elements due to CSS `transform: tranlate3d()`.

Since there's no good fix the these CSS issues, I was wondering if anyone knew of a solution to mimic functionality of the Facebook Chat/Event Ticker sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar using CSS3 resizing on the fixed sidebar (mine was on the left) and adjusting the main page's margin-left when the sidebar size changed. You could likely do something similar on the sidebar first, then split the sidebar in two the same way.

```js
var sizeme = 200,
    sizeItBro = function () {
      if ($("#sidebar").width() != sizeme) {
        sizeme = $("#sidebar").width() + 40;
        $("#main").css("margin-left", sizeme + "px").text(sizeme + " pixels of margin.");
      }
    };
window.setInterval(sizeItBro, 150);
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#main {
  margin-left:200px;
  min-height:100%;
  padding:20px;
}
#sidebar {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background:#ffa;
  width:200px;
  min-width:100px;
  max-width:500px;
  resize:horizontal;
  overflow:auto;
  border-right:2px ridge #fe9;
  padding:20px;
}
#tophalf {
  background:#fe9;
  height:300px;
  min-height:100px;
  max-height:500px;
  resize:vertical;
  overflow:auto;
  border-bottom:2px ridge #fe9;
  margin:-20px -20px 20px;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">Main Content</div>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="tophalf">Sidebar A</div>
    <p>Sidebar B</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the insight -- can you provide any more details, or perhaps a JSFiddle minimal implementation example for me to look at?  I'm a bit confused as your answer is a tad bit vague.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/davmillar/m3TbT/

A bit sloppy, but you get the idea. The main issue here is that the resize handles are always in the bottom right corner.